# positive operator on finite dimensional real Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if operators ‎$  S ‎‎$ and $‎‎T‎$ ‎ on finite-dimensional Hilbert space ‎$ H $‎ are positive and commute ( ‎$ ST=TS $)‎, then their composition is also positive. But i don't know that,  is necessary commute condition? in other words, is  ‎there ‎exist ‎positive ‎operators‎ ‎$  S ‎‎$ and $‎‎T‎$ ‎ on finite-dimensional  real Hilbert space ‎$ H $ such that  ‎$ ST‎\neq‎TS $ but ‎$ ST $ ‎is ‎positive?‎

Answer (score 2):

Sure? For a simple example in $\mathbb R^2$: Take $S=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $T=S^T$. Then both $S,T$ are positive, as
$$ x^TSx = x^TTx = x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2 $$
As $|x_1x_2| \leq \max(x_1^2,x_2^2)$ and if $\max(x_1^2,x_2^2)=0$ then also $x_1x_2=0$ we see that this is always positive for $x\neq0$.

Also $S,T$ do not commute, as $ST =
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ and $TS= 
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}\right)$. But we have
$$ x^T ST x = 2x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 +x_2^2 = x_1^2 + (x_1+x_2)^2$$
so $ST$ (and similarly $TS$) are positive.

Answer (score 0):

If $ST$ is positive on a complex Hilbert space, then it's self-adjoint as well:
$$ST=(ST)^*=T^*S^*=TS\,,$$
so commutativity is necessary.

Comment: Positive implies self-adjoint for complex vector spaces. It doesn't work for $\mathbb  R^{n}$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes. Exactly right .Positive implies self-adjoint for complex vector spaces.

Comment: Positive implies self-adjoint for complex Hilbert spaces, not real Hilbert space. For example ‎$ T(x,y) =(2x+2y, 2y) $ ‎on‎ ‎$ R‎^{2}‎ $ ‎is ‎positive ‎but ‎is ‎not ‎self-adjoint.‎